# GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE) returns incorrect value in Win 2012

Tags: windows, windows-8

I am trying to get the size of the button in Windows in my project using windows API GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE).

Whereas GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE) returns '36' in Windows 8 and I am able to adjust the tool bar window correctly.
But it returns '22' in Windows Server 2012 and I am not able to adjust my tool bar properly.

A sample code snippet is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

int main()
{    
   printf("Value SM_CXSIZE: %d", GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE));   
   return 0;
}
```

Can you please suggest a way to accomplish this.

Comment: You are shooting the messenger, surely the problem is in your "adjust" code not being able to cope with small caption buttons.

Comment: The output of the above code itself returns '22' for Win Server 2012 and '36' for Win 8. Win 8 and Windows 2012 have same size of buttons. This code is working fine with XP, Server 2003, Win 7.